# How to convert a powershell output to a md (Markdown) file?

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, markdown

I have the following code:

```
$xml        = 'C:\Users\jonb\Desktop\bom.xml'
$ns = @{a = 'http://cyclonedx.org/schema/bom/1.2'} 
$xPath = '//a:component'
$components = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath $xPath -Namespace $ns

foreach ($component in $components) {    
  $name = Select-Xml -Xml $component.Node -XPath './/a:name/text()'-Namespace $ns 
  $version = Select-Xml -Xml $component.Node -XPath './/a:version/text()'-Namespace $ns
  $lic_cond = Select-Xml -Xml $component.Node -XPath './/a:license/a:id/text()'-Namespace $ns

  $license = $(If ($lic_cond) {$lic_cond} Else {"NA"}) 

  $finalObject = [pscustomobject]@{
        'Name'          = $name
        'Version'       = $version
        'License'      = $license
    }
   Write-Output $finalObject
}
```

Now I would like to convert my $finalObject to a MarkDown Table. Are there any possibilities here?

I have seen that there is a ConvertFrom-Markdown command. However, I did not get anywhere with this command.

Thanks for your help

Comment: "*md file?*" (MarkDown is just a superset of plain text), I guess you want to convert your `$finalObject` to a MarkDown **Table**...

Comment: Exactly I want convert my $finalObject to a MarkDown Table

Comment: Google for `ConvertTo-MarkDown`. There are several to be found

Answer (score 4):

Just a quick and dirty one:

```
function ConvertTo-MarkDownTable {
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, ValueFromPipeLine = $True)] $InputObject
    )
    Begin { $Index = 0 }
    Process {
        if ( !$Index++ ) {
            '|' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -Join '|') + '|'
            '|' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.ForEach({ '-' }) -Join '|') + '|'
        }
        '|' + ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value -Join '|') + '|'
    }
}
```

**usage:**

```
$finalObject = 
    [pscustomobject]@{ 'Name' = 'name1'; 'Version' = 'version1'; 'License' = 'license1' },
    [pscustomobject]@{ 'Name' = 'name2'; 'Version' = 'version2'; 'License' = 'license2' }

$finalObject |ConvertTo-MarkDownTable
```

**Yields:**

```
|Name|Version|License|
|-|-|-|
|name1|version1|license1|
|name2|version2|license2|
```

**Converted in StackOverflow:**

| Name | Version | License |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | version1 | license1 |
| name2 | version2 | license2 |